# Find multiple categories of promises in texts

Tags: nlp

I have conversations a customer with an agent (without punctuation). There are phrases of several categories of promises that an agent gave to a customer (call back, make an appointment, etc.). It has been done manually. Altogether 12 categories. Now I'm thinking of creating an algorithm for this. I am thinking to do this task in two steps.

1. In the first step, I need to create an algorithm that can find an
   end and a beginning of all promises. This algorithm has to insert a
   start tag and an end tag.
2. The second step is to create a classifier that would label a promise
   to the necessary categories.

As I understand, the second step is well known and this is called text classification. But for the first step, I could not find any articles and github repositories. But I think it is an important NLP task and there must be information on this. Maybe are there approaches that solve two steps at the same time?

**Update**

Just sample an agent's transcript (in reality it is more difficult):

```
hi my name is ben how can i help you yes good what about i can help probably yes sir do you have a problem with internet connection i see let do you need a help at place okay i see so what i can do i can arrange appointment with technical will it be good for you great can i help you with something else you okey okey to have a great day you too
```

Promise here is

```
i can arrange appointment with technical
```

Answer (score 1):

That would be a [sequence labeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_labeling) task, the most common type is [Named Entity Recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition), you'll find many examples about it but you can train a custom system with your data. The traditional method is [Conditional Random Fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_random_field), there are a good few libraries available.

Side note: usually a single CRF model is used to do both detecting and labeling at once (your steps 1 and 2).